# Can I ask a clear question about how to do something stupid?

Tags: discussion

This meta question is inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556418/python-only-use-mem-cached-memory-for-process) community response.

In this particular example, I may have asked how to do something stated very clearly what I was trying to accomplish. Based on feedback I have recieved, it is clear that what I wanted to do has not yet been done, and not advisable. I now have gotten back up to 0 in voting, but at one point was highly negative. To be clear - I am **happy about the comments** I recieved which helped me get more context on the problem, and **frustrated with the downvotes**.

I guess my real question is -> Is reputation on a question supposed to be related to why I want to do something, or even if doing something is a good idea, if I was very clear about what I asked to begin with?

For example if I ask the following clear question:

"**When doing [stacksort](https://gkoberger.github.io/stacksort/) in python how do I pass my list to the web form?**"

I would get a large amount of voting backlash for trying to do stacksort because it is slow, and unreliable, and likely would be a very [bad idea](http://xkcd.com/1185/).

If I want to dig my own grave too deep, I feel it would be great if the stack overflow community could hand me an efficient shovel at the same time as warning me that I am going to get stuck and die.

Comment: "...do stacksort in python for my startup?" is not the problematic part of that question. Asking for library recommendations is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @BilltheLizard -> You are correct :) I modified and tried to ask a more well phrased ridiculous example question

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate - but propose the words in my question title are more google-able.

Comment: Definitely no contest there. Anyone searching will now find the link to the original, so thank you for clearing a path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is reputation on a question supposed to be related to why I want to do something, or even if doing something is a good idea, if I was very clear about what I asked to begin with?

Votes are there to, among other things, indicate how *useful* the content is.  Asking how to shoot yourself in the foot isn't a useful question, no matter how clearly you ask it or how on topic it is, and the votes are going to indicate that.

Comment: I suppose this is why the Reversal badge exists: to reward answers that school questions on just how ridiculous they are. [Case in point.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)